# Creating a non Rectangle UI in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So what I want to do is basically create a graph based off four numbers I get during runtime to create something like a personality chart. The user takes a quiz and based on which answer they give, I increase a running total for that attribute. At the end, based off of the numbers calculated turn each of the four numbers into vertices of a `RectTransform` in perhaps a panel or maybe something else entirely.

For each of the four categories there is a total of 10 possible points. The overall shape of the background panel is a diamond(i.e. rotated square), with each of the four corners representing an attribute.

I've tried messing with the RectTransforms and such but the shape always turns out a rectangle(Duh! its a **Rect**Transform). But The problem is that I need it to **not** be a rectangle. Is there a way to do this in Unity or through any other means?

The black polygon would be an example of the type of shape I would want to create.

[image: Example graph in paint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research on the topic I found a script that does exactly what I want and more, which is really nice. I'll leave a link to it below.

https://github.com/CiaccoDavide/Unity-UI-Polygon/blob/master/UIPolygon.cs